# How to reference column on inserted table in after trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-trigger

I have an update to process on a trigger when a specific code in the column is input.  When I reference the inserted table, which shows in the intellisence dropdown list when I type inserted I get the error:

> The multipart identifier "inserted.contact" could not be bound.

Any idea how to reference a column in the inserted table for a trigger? Also, why is it better to use the inserted table than the existing table?

USE PCUnitTest
GO

```
UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = T.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(inserted.Contact) T --"the multipart identifier "inserted.contact" could not be bound"
WHERE C.Key1 = '76'
;
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your data layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bring in `inserted` just like any table:

```
UPDATE P
    SET P.First_Name = T.ForeName,
        P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name,
        P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM PCUnitTest.dbo.People P JOIN
     GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
     ON P.People_ID = C.Key4 JOIN
     inserted i
     ON i.?? = c.?? CROSS APPLY
     dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T 
WHERE C.Key1 = '76';
```

The only question is what columns you use for the `JOIN`.  The `??` are for your column names.

Comment: thanks how do i know it's the inserted table from the contact1 table that the user just updated? contact1 is the table the user just updated, so possibly it doesn't need to be in the query since the new value will be in the inserted table. It lookslike I would use this.
UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = T.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON i.KEY4 = P.People_ID
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
WHERE i.Key1 = '76-ENR'
AND P.PEOPLE_ID = i.KEY4

Comment: @ERPise Hello again! The `Inserted` table is only populated with data after an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.  If this is a trigger on `Contact1`, then any time such a statement is run on that table, `Inserted` will be populated with the rows from the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  The trigger will **not** catch values from the `Inserted` table after such a statement is run against any other table.